My email server IP is blacklisted, how can I resolve it?
The IP of our email server 154.116.254.147 was added to the UCEPROTECTL2 blacklist. The error message we received is as follows:
"I am deeply sorry, but I was not able to deliver your mail to the following addresses:
xxx@hotmail.com: 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [154.116.254.147] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list (S3150). You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. [BL02EPF0001A0FA.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-16T08:16:07.271Z 08DC73D31DA204C5]
This is a permanent delivery failure. The delivery has been tried 0 times and will not be rescheduled again."
So far, we have not tried any interventions.
Additional Details:

Server operating system: Ubuntu
Email server: Axigen

What can we do to remove our IP from the UCEPROTECTL2 blacklist and ensure our emails are delivered correctly?
Thanks!

How do you know the messages are not getting through because of UCEPROTECTL2?

Hotmail/Outlook.com does not use the UCEPROTECTL2 blacklist. You should look at Outlook.com official tools to resolve this issue: https://sendersupport.olc.protection.outlook.com/pm/services.aspx
Besides that? UCEPROTECT is scam ( https://blog.sucuri.net/2021/02/uceprotect-when-rbls-go-bad.html ). No e-mail provider/self-hosted user should use UCEPROTECT...

https://sender.office.com/ could help you to whitelist it, or let you give another IP ore mostly, move to a business confirm hosting platform

I would start by updating the whois info and add an abuse email address. Secondly, I would take action against those within your network which are carrying out abuse. I personally block most African addresses since they provide no method for complaints about abuse.
